# Not able to update Pre loaded System Application through Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have developed an Application for a device Manufacturer which will be Pre loaded as System Application into the Device. The Device Manufacturer has Pre loaded the system application and it is available in the system image of the device. Now the requirement from the client is to update this system Application through play store in the similar way Google Play Services is updated.
I have uploaded a higher version of Application on the Google play store and once I update the App , initially the App crashes and the update is not reflected on the device until the device is rebooted. But the Preloaded applications like Google Maps, Google Play Services gets updated as soon as it is downloaded from the play store.

I have followed the steps mentioned on Google Support for updating System App :[Updating System App through Play Store](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en) (Scroll to last of the page)
Please Let me know if some one has any idea about this.

The crash logs  that I am getting are as follows :

```
06-21 18:40:40.748 2577-2577/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.harman.panasonicaicollection, PID: 2577
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.harman.panasonicaicollection/com.harman.panasonicaicollection.activities.MainDashBoardActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2419)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2479)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:152)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5429)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:475)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                     at com.harman.panasonicaicollection.activities.MainDashBoardActivity.onCreate(MainDashBoardActivity.java:53)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6311)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2372)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2479) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:152) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5429) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: did you fix it? i have same problem. can you help me?

Comment: Yes , unfortunately i had added a flag in manifest `android:persistent = true` which basically means to start the application process as soon as it is killed by the system and can only be used by system app. So when my app was getting updated the system was not able to install the update due to this flag untill the reboot was done. So removal of above flag helped me.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks!